# Problem getting Google Remote Desktop to work

Tags: 14.04, remote-access

I am trying to get Google Remote Desktop to work on Ubuntu 14.04 with the Unity desktop but every time I click on Share it just downloads a fresh copy of `chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb`. However the service is already installed, and event if I humour' Chromium' and reinstall the service I still get the same problem.

The service can be started and stopped from the command line so it is certainly installed. However I have noticed that I am not getting the log file `/tmp/chrome_remote_desktop_` which Google's instructions reference. I also noticed that the Ubuntu installer complained about the package and I needed to force it to install.

I have created the `.chrome-remote-desktop-session script`, made it executable and inserted  the command line,

```
exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "gnome-session --session=ubuntu"
```

I'd be very interested to know if anyone has found a way past this problem.